# Ruby | How to reference the console object

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to reference the console in Ruby as an object?
Like:

```rb
console.puts(value)
```

The reason I want to print to the console like this is that I want to make a reusable function which can either print to the console or to a file:

```rb
def put_value(obj, value)
  obj.puts(value)
end

# To console
put_value(console, "Testing")

# To file
file = File.open("test.txt", "w")
put_value(file, "Testing")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "console object"? Is there any reason why `IO#puts`, which allows you to write to any arbitrary `IO` stream is not working for you?

Comment: Not sure what `IO#puts` is. I am new to Ruby. All I was looking for was to pass the standard output stream as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `STDOUT` in place of `console`. 
`STDOUT` connects you to the output stream of current tty, pipes it output there and has the same API as `IO` (like in your `File` below)

```
def put_value(obj, value)
  obj.puts(value)
end

# To console
put_value(STDOUT, "Testing")
#=> Testing

# To file
file = File.open("test.txt", "w")
put_value(file, "Testing")
#=> nil, but Testing is written to test.txt
```

Comment: Alternatively `$stdout` (current standard output stream, `STDOUT` is just the original one) or if `console` is taken literally: [`IO.console`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-c-console).